# Jquery clilck event on unordered list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have two unordered lists: one is a list of products, a second is a list of categories to filter categories by.

In the code below, the first function to toggle the 'open' class on product list items works, but the second does not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#products').on('click', 'li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("open")
  });

  $('#filters').on('click', 'li', function () {
    //set or reset category array
    var catarray = [];
    //set categories
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    $("#products li").hide();
    //if no categories, show all 
    if ($(".clicked").length == 0) {
      $("#products li").fadeIn("slow")
      return;
    }
    $("#products li").fadeOut("slow")
    //collate categories
    $(".clicked").each(function () {
      var category = $(this).attr("id");
      catarray.push(category)
    });
    var catarray = catarray.join('.')
    var catarray = "." + catarray
    //filter based on categories
    $("#products li").filter(catarray).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

Am i missing something about the way Jquery .on calls work?

Comment: Can you add in examples of the lists?

Comment: I'd suggest inserting an alert at the beginning inside the on() statement, see if it alerts.  If so move it further and further down.

Comment: I think maybe you're missing a space in your join separator, like `var catarray = catarray.join(' .');` as it is now you are filtering on products that have all the classes specified, rather than any one of the classes specified

Comment: Never mind guys, I took the suggestion of Dylan and checked my HTML. ALl sorted. Thanks for your time